# Specified cast is not valid - Xamarin:

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy intentando sin éxito leer unos datos ya almacenados en `Firebase Firestore` con `Xamarin.Android`.

La app ya almacena datos, así que detalles como el `google-services.json` están bien. Lo que creo tengo mal es el método para castear (cast) los datos.

Un botón activa este método (En este método da el error):

```
private void LeerDatos_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{            
  FirebaseFirestore database = GetDataBase();
  **En esta línea se quiebra/Error** 
  database.Collection("Usuarios")
  .Document("KsX4z8JuugOrBMmL6337")
  .Get()
  .AddOnSuccessListener((Android.Gms.Tasks.IOnSuccessListener)this);
}
```

Comment: El parseo que estas haciendo es el problema, que objeto te trae? deberias debugear y fijarte a que debes hacer el cast.

Comment: @RamiroBarone le meti un 'Try' y trate debugear pero no se interpretar el 'database', no se que buscar y el Try no me da mas detalles.

Comment: (Android.Gms.Tasks.IOnSuccessListener)this -> este es tu cast

Comment: Estuve leyendo un poco la doc de firestore y veo diferente como quieres obtener la info con respecto a lo que muestra google. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=es

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solucionado.**

El problema era que en la declaración de la clase sobre la que estaba trabajando tenía que agregar esto:

```
IOnSuccessListener
```

Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
public class LoginAux : Activity, IOnSuccessListener
    { ...
```

Para que el método quedara sin necesidad de una conversión o cast implícita, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
database.Collection("Usuarios").Document("KsX4l8JuugOrBMmL6337").Get().AddOnSuccessListener(this);
```

Gracias por los consejos.